# Custom view (button) background selector doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-custom-view, android-selector

I have simple custom button:

```
public class myButton extends Button {
    public myButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        commonConstructorCode();
    }


    public myButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        commonConstructorCode();
    }

  public myButton (Context context) {
    super(context);
    commonConstructorCode();
  }

      private void commonConstructorCode() {
                this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction(); 

                    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
                    {
                      //Just to be sure that we removed all callbacks, 
                      // which should have occurred in the ACTION_UP
                      removeCallbacks(repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable);

                      //Perform the default click action.
                      performClick();
                      //if(v.isEnabled()){
                      //Schedule the start of repetitions after a one half second delay.
                      postDelayed(repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable, initialRepeatDelay);
                      //} else {
                        //  removeCallbacks(repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable);
                      //}
                    }
                    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                      //Cancel any repetition in progress.
                      removeCallbacks(repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable);
                    }
                //Returning true here prevents performClick() from getting called 
                // in the usual manner, which would be redundant, given that we are 
                // already calling it above.
                return true;
      }
    });
      }
}
```

with selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_standard" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

set by

```
<com.blabla.myButton
    ...
    background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

Background in "normal" state is fine. But other states don't work at all. What is strange - when I change

```
<com.blabla.myButton
```

to

```
<Button
```

selector works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I added commonConstructorCode().

Comment: well it's strange. I tried doing a custom button with your selector XML file and all is fine.

Comment: I've tested it on a device with Android 4.2 and 2.3.7 - both with the same, wrong result.

Comment: I add selector background using a style. But setting it directly doesn't work too.

Comment: This should work. I think you need to provide us with more code, I suspect something else you are doing is interfering with the process.

Comment: the only difference between my code and yours is the `commonConstructorCode`, so probably the mistake is there

Comment: Ok, please look at it again, I've added that part ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated your code and got the custom button selector working but setting:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Blah blah blah....
            return false; // this was return true
        }
    });
```

According to the android docs, public boolean onTouch(),

> Returns: True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

So returning true indicates your method has consumed the event and seems to stop it perculating up the hierarchy and triggering the selector states.

Comment: Great! I also removed performClick() to prevent double click caused by returning false. Thank you ;-).

Comment: Happy to help. It was bugging me so I had to sit down and try it out;

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting this on the custom xml view.

```
android:focusable = "true"
```

I had a similar issue and setting focusable to true allowed the view to read the correct state and apply the selector.

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't help.

Comment: Strange that normal button tag works and custom one doesn't. mighty strange.

Comment: Just a thought, you could try adding super.onTouchEvent(event); to the top of your onTouch. Maybe something isn't being received by the Button class that you are extending from, that it needs to do the selector state changes.

Comment: Nice idea. "The method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Object" I have to try. Same result for "super.onTouch(v, event);"

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of your class, use following code:

```
this.setBackgroundResource(drawable.button_selector);
```

I try it. Works perfectly